# Apache configuration: how to get quick feedback?

Tags: apache

When writing configuration files for Apache web server I would like to have a quick feedback loop.

I, for example have a script that doesn't seem to work. It is either not picked up, or the variables I use are not set, or maybe overriding is not allowed. How to debug this?

I expected to at least print some debug log statements like `REQUEST_URI: %{REQUEST_URI}`. Can't find such a thing.

Comment: apachectl configtest for checking the config files

Comment: that is a binary in the project?

Answer (score 1):

`apachectl` is a front end to the Apache HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) server. It is designed to help the administrator control the functioning of the Apache httpd daemon.

Here is a [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html) to the documentation.

Different platform might use different binary names such as apache, apache2 or  apache2ctl. To test the configuration - just run:

```
apachectl configtest
# or, depending on your OS
httpd -t
```

**EDIT**
If you are trying to debug your virtual host configuration, you may find the Apache -S command line switch useful. That is, type the following command:

```
httpd -S
```

This command will dump out a description of how Apache parsed the configuration file

Comment: How does this help to inspect values or evaluate conditions?

Comment: you can get more information usin `-S` key, see updated answer